# Limit git hook to a single repository

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I use gitlab to manage a few repositories on a local dev server and have implemented hooks to automatically deploy projects when a commit is successful. This works fine but unfortunately my post-receive hook runs when I commit to any repository, not just the repository that the hook is for.

**How can I limit my hook so that it only runs when a push is made to a specific repository?**

Comment: Just add the hook locally, under the `.git/hooks` directory in your project/repository.

Comment: The above comment should be entered as an answer, since it does indeed tell you what you need to know

Comment: I currently have the hook in 'repositories/somegroup/somename.git/hooks' and the file is called 'post-receive'

Comment: Which version of GitLab are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using GitLab Omnibus Community Edition 8.0.5. From what i understand, you are looking for custom hooks so you can perform actions only on a specific repository. For this GitLab introduced custom git hooks feature for *gitlab-shell* version 2.2.0 (which requires GitLab 7.5+). You will have to create a new directory called custom_hooks in 'repositories/somegroup/somename.git/' directory. For my setup, it looks like as shown below:

[image]

Note: In my case, i also observed that if i removed the *default* post-receive hook file from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks folder, my post-receive hook kept in custom_hooks directory stopped working. So make sure the default hooks are not removed. Just place your custom hooks in your custom_hooks directory and all should be fine.

For more details, please refer http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html

Comment: That seems to have worked. for me I saw that my post_receive hook in hooks was actually a shortcut to the file in the gitlab-shell folder. Removing the shortcut but keeping the post-recieve file in the hooks folder seemed to solve this for me. I had to remove the text from the post-receive file in my gitlab-shell folder. Self hosted Gitlab 6.0.2 10b0b8f

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm glad my answer helped! :)